# C# cross class enum visibility - Possible?

Tags: c#, class, enums

so i have a class ClassA that contains an enum MyEnum, and a class ClassB that references that class (different Projects) and so in ClassB i have a

```
using ClassA;
```

clause and  i can access that enum using something like

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.EnumValue;
```

Now on a third project i have my Windows form and it has a clause like

```
using ClassB;
```

Now what can i add in ClassB to acess that enum on my windows Form? Is it even Possible? i would like to avoid having to add ClassA to my form just to access an enum.

The idea is that ClassB is sort of a manager between my form and the functionality in ClassA - but i would like to get access to that enum as it makes a lot of tasks easier

Comment: can you not declare the enum publicly outside of a class? Then you can access it when using the namespace that it is in.

Comment: @537mfb - "i would like to avoid having to add ClassA to my form just to access an enum." - Why?

Comment: @Buzzz - will look into that - ClassA is in fact a big project that i didn't create so was trying to avoid messing with it

Comment: @Ramhound - Why would i want to reference a all project in my form just to access a little enum in one of it's classes? what a waste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upvoted you all the other day since all you comments aided me in finding the best solution for my case.

The solution i ultimatly followed was to refactor everything so that i managed to get all code that required that enum (or anything else) from ClassA into ClassB and have ClassB report back to my main project through events the results of the operations so that i could update the UI with the results as they come in.

I think this is ultimatly the best solution for this problem

Answer (score 4):

The logical thing in this situation is to make the enum independent of `ClassA` and make it public so that it is available throughout your solution.

### Edit

After reading the comments, if you really want to avoid changing `ClassA` you could try to create a second enum and just cast one value to the other. For example, in an extension method:

```
public enum EnumB
{
    // make it equivalent to enum in ClassA
}

public static EnumB ToEnumB(this EnumA enumAValue) 
{
    EnumB newValue = (EnumB)(int)enumAValue;
}
```

Comment: will look into that - see my comment to Buzzzz above

Comment: @537mfb - I understand your concern, but if you really need to use that enum in several places outside of ClassA, it really doesn't belong in ClassA. Any crazy workarounds you can come up with will only complicate your life and make the design of the application less logical.

Comment: true - but like i said, i didn't create the project where class A is - am just using it

Comment: @537mfb - Maybe just use a second, equivalent enum and a simple conversion then? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting - how does this differ from emannelle's answer? seems similar

Comment: To be honest, I hadn't even checked the other answers :p
But I wouldn't place the new `enum` inside `ClassB` or you might run into the same problem in the future. Also, I do my conversion in an extension method. Not that it's better by definition, but it answers the question "how does this differ..." ;)
Oh, yeah, and I think you can better cast an `enum` to `int`, since that is the inherent base value of an `enum`.

Answer (score 2):

> i would like to avoid having to add ClassA to my form just to access an enum

You can't. If it is *defined* in the assembly where `ClassA` resides, you *must* reference that assembly.

If you are not talking about classes that live in different assemblies, you can put the enumeration in a file of its own and declare it as `public` - this will give access to it from any point in your code (which is normal practice for enumerations).

---

Update:

You can create an additional project containing shared objects, such as public enumerations and interfaces and reference that in your other projects.

Comment: will look into that - see my comment to Buzzz above

Comment: your update sounds like an interesting solution - still adds an extra using on my form though - will try all ways see what goes better - really didn't want tp mess with that project but seems like the only way to go about it

Answer (score 1):

`Using` clause is just a shortcut to avoid writing a namespace (or in this case a class) everytime you need to reference an element defined there.

If you don't like to write

```
ClassA.MyEnum..
```

you must write

```
using ClassA;
.....
 My Enum....
```

This is the way to access to ClassA.MyEnum from your form.
Anyway, if you don't like this solution, you can't re-define the Enum in another place.
You could create another enum called ClassB.MyEnum and then map any value of a ClassB.MyEnum to a ClassA.MyEnum. Here a sample for that workaround, I don't know if it's useful.

```
public class ClassB
 {
  public enum MyEnum
    {
     MyValue1,
     MyValue2
     }

   public static MyEnum Convert (ClassA.MyEnum originalValue)
    {
     return (MyEnum)Enum.Parse (typeof (MyEnum), originalValue.ToString());
    }
 }
```

I suggest to move MyEnum outside ClassA.

Comment: i know what a using clause is for - that wasn't my question - as to move enum out see my comment to Buzzz above - will look into the mapping option too

Comment: I understand; just tried to give you all the elements I know to help you.  :-)

Comment: @537mfb Look at the sample given.

Comment: thnx - i wish i could just put an alias for it in my classB namespace and access it in the form through that alias - would be so much easier